# Disable the enter key when the input form is unfilled

Tags: c#, search-form

I am creating a URL search form where the users can press the enter key to make a decision.
How can I disable the enter key if the user presses it when there are no letters or numbers entered in the search form?
As it is now, if the user presses the enter key while the input form is not filled out, it will crash.

```
private void txtUrl_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)

            wbSample.Navigate(txtUrl.Text);
    }
```

When the user types in any URL that exists on the web and presses enter, it will display any site via the code below.

`wbSample.Navigate(txtUrl.Text);`

Comment: You could just add an additional if statement and check `string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtUrl.Text)`? Or perform more advanced checking using Regex or similar. Then return out the method if not valid. Or am I missing something?

Comment: In every TextChanged or SelectedIndexChanged etc. (depending on the contol type) call a method checking the input. In this method set `btnEnter.Enabled = true` or `false`, depending on the outcome of the test.

Comment: why not simply `if (e.Key == Key.Enter && !String.IsNullOrempty(searchForm.Text))`?

Comment: @Chriz remembers Monica
This system will direct the user to that arbitrary site only when the user enters an arbitrary URL and presses the enter key.
If you replace the code `if (e.Key == Key.Enter)

            wbSample.Navigate(txtUrl.Text);` with `if (e.Key == Key.Enter && !String.IsNullOrempty(searchForm.Text))?`, the enter key will be disabled whether the URL is present or not.

Comment: Resolved. Thank you very much for help.